# Using Whitebox plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, whitebox-tools

QGIS 3.8.3 running in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

I've installed Whitebox Tools and the Whitebox plugin and am able to obtain, for example, data on a .las file using 'Lidarinfo', so the system appears to be working (at least at this level).

However, attempting to use LidarNearestNeighbourGridding produces the following:

> Algorithm 'LidarNearestNeighbourGridding' starting… Input parameters:
>   { 'exclude_cls' : '1,3,4', 'input' :
>   '/home/nick/Desktop/SU5771_P_9194_20131130_20131201.las', 'maxz' :
>   None, 'minz' : None, 'output' :
>   '/home/nick/Desktop/SU5771_P_9194_20131130_20131201.tif', 'parameter'
>   : 0, 'radius' : 2.5, 'resolution' : 1, 'returns' : 0 }
>
> WhiteBoxTools command: "/home/nick/whitebox_tools/WBT/whitebox_tools"
>   --run=LidarNearestNeighbourGridding --input="/home/nick/Desktop/SU5771_P_9194_20131130_20131201.las" --parameter="elevation" --returns="all" --resolution=1.0 --radius=2.5 --exclude_cls="1,3,4" --minz=0.0 --maxz=0.0 --output="/home/nick/Desktop/SU5771_P_9194_20131130_20131201.tif" -v WhiteBoxTools command output:
>
> ---
>
> - Welcome to LidarNearestNeighbourGridding *
>
> ---
>
> Performing interpolation...
>
> Reading input LAS file...
>
> No points found in
>   /home/nick/Desktop/SU5771_P_9194_20131130_20131201.las
>
> Finished interpolating homenickDesktopSU5771_P_9194_20131130_20131201
>   (1 of 1)
>
> Elapsed Time (including I/O): 0.146s
>
> Execution completed in 0.29 seconds Results: {'output':
>   }
>
> Loading resulting layers The following layers were not correctly
>   generated.
>
> - /home/nick/Desktop/SU5771_P_9194_20131130_20131201.tif
>
> You
>   can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more
>   information about the execution of the algorithm.

"No points found in /home/nick/Desktop/SU5771_P_9194_20131130_20131201.las" would appear to be the operative part of this.

The file is a UK Environment Agency .laz file unzipped using laszip and was supplied already classified.

I'm very new to processing lidar data but I have produced DTMs using LAStools and also using PDAL.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You can try assigning values to the _minz_ and _maxz_ parameters.

Comment: Thanks very much, this worked. If you would care to post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Nice to be able to help you, Nick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know the plugin or its code, but this part of the command attracts attention:

> --minz=0.0 --maxz=0.0

It is probably not the expected behavior, but the algorithm seems to be filtering the input points to interpolate only among those that have a height equal to zero.

Try to establish specific values, within the range of heights of your source data, to be assigned to the `minz` and `maxz` parameters of the point filter to be interpolated.